# Reference Error: "UrlShortener" is not defined sheets google

Tags: excel, scripting, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, url-shortener

I'm trying this code:

```
  function onOpen() {

SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

.createMenu("Shorten")

.addItem("Go !!","rangeShort")

 .addToUi()  
}

function rangeShort() {

  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(), data = range.getValues();

var output = [];

 for(var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i++) {

 var url = UrlShortener.Url.insert({longUrl: data[i][0]});

 output.push([url.id]);

}

range.offset(0,1).setValues(output);

}
```

but It has an error:

> in line 12  Reference Error: "UrlShortener" is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the Google Script, go to Resources > Advanced Google Services and enable the URL Shortener API.